# Value of type Byte() cannot be converted to byte

Tags: vb.net

I need create an array(), and add two items into this array. I got the error as title. How can I add the value into byte()?

```
Dim keypair As byte() = {privatekey.ID, publickey.ID}
```

and I also tried

```
Dim keypair(0) = privatekey.ID
Dim keypair(1) = publickey.ID
```

Both not working. The privatekey.Id is byte type.

Comment: Based on the error, the `ID` property must be typed as a byte array.  So, what are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want the end result to be a single-dimension byte array with the two ID's concatenated together?  Or do you want the end result to be a two dimensional array (i.e. a list of arrays -- array item per ID)?

Comment: By looking at your previous questions you seem to be using the `NCryptoki` library. If you look at [**their documentation for the `Key.ID` property**](http://www.cryptware.com/apidoc/ncryptoki/html/P_Cryptware_NCryptoki_Key_ID.htm) you'll see that it is of type `Byte()` (a byte _**array**_) and _**not**_ a single `Byte`. What is it that you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: Hi @StevenDoggart I just want the result to be a single-dimension byte array with these two IDs. thanks

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks, I saw the code, but I just want to put these two ID into one Array, and my code is not working. if the ID is byte() type. why is not working?

Comment: Because a `Byte()` is an array of _**single bytes**_. `keypair` expects this: `{Byte, Byte, Byte, ...}` but you're trying to do this: `{Byte(), Byte(), Byte(), ...}`. _**Why**_ do you want them in the same array?

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks for your help, Seven's code is working for me. I want them into the same array, because I want my function return these two values.

Comment: Just be aware that Steven's code will put _**all the values**_ in the same array, not the arrays themselves. Therefore you won't be able to tell where one array starts and the other ends unless they are of fixed size.

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you. Its really good to know. I will remember it.

Comment: I agree with @VisualVincent.  While that does stuff all the data into a single object, it's not the ideal way to "return" both values.  Unless you know the exact size of both ID arrays, you won't be able to tell where one ends and the next one begins.  The typical preferred way to return multiple values is to use a custom class or `Tuple`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to concatenate two arrays together in .NET.  If you want some alternatives for how to do it, you can search for ".NET array concatenate" and find all sorts of options.  However, probably the simplest approach is to use LINQ:

```
Dim keyPair As Byte() = privatekey.ID.Concat(publickey.ID).ToArray()
```

Note: this is based on your request, in the comments above, to concatenate the two arrays into a single one-dimensional array.  While there are times when doing so may be necessary, it does seem like an odd choice in most scenarios.

Comment: Good thing I checked before posting, I was about to post something similar